# How to keep user score in visual basic even if user failed validation first time?

Tags: vb.net, validation, visual-studio-2012

Hello I am currently making an hangman game where you guess a randomly selected word and you have three rounds. Each time you win a round you gain 10 points, however if you don't guess the word before you run out of the 10 generous attempts. You will lose the round not gain anything.

After you win you three games of hangman, you are shown a new input text box in a high score form to input your name to save your high score to be displayed on the high score form and it has validation in (Meaning the user is required have at least one character inside the text box). This is where my main problem is, my input box will save your name and your points if you pass validation first time. However if you didn't pass validation first time but pass it the second time, your name is saved however your high score will be saved but only with one point. Sorry for my bad English, but is there anyway to keep the amount of points the user scores even if they failed validation first time instead of changing it to 1 point? Here is my code (Sorry for the bad indention):

**Hangman Game Code (This is where the user gets their points from)**

```
            Imports System.IO
      Public Class Hangman
      'Public Variables
     Public AttemptsLeft As Integer = 0
     Public Rounds As Integer = 1
      Public LetterChosen As Char
      Dim EndWord() As Char
       Dim AppPath As String = Application.StartupPath()
      Dim FileRead() As String
       Public GameWinner As Boolean = True
       Dim HangmanShapes As New List(Of PowerPacks.Shape)
            Public ScoreForRound As Integer
               Dim NewControls As New List(Of Button)
               Dim GameWord As New List(Of Label)

'Form Load code
Private Sub Hangman_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Load Word Game Code
    If File.Exists(AppPath & "/wordlist.txt") Then
        FileRead = IO.File.ReadAllLines(AppPath & "/wordlist.txt")
        Dim RandomWord As New List(Of String)
        For i = 0 To FileRead.Length - 1
            RandomWord.Add(FileRead(i))
        Next
        Dim random As New Random() 'Using this to randomise each word
        EndWord = RandomWord(random.Next(0, RandomWord.Count - 1)).ToUpper.ToCharArray 'Will put each character of the randomly chosen word into the labels.
        Score.Text = UScore
        Round.Text = Rounds
        Letter1.Text = EndWord(0)
        Letter1.Visible = False
        Letter2.Text = EndWord(1)
        Letter2.Visible = False
        Letter3.Text = EndWord(2)
        Letter3.Visible = False
        Letter4.Text = EndWord(3)
        Letter4.Visible = False
        Letter5.Text = EndWord(4)
        Letter5.Visible = False
        Letter6.Text = EndWord(5)
        Letter6.Visible = False
        'Attempts left code
    End If
    With HangmanShapes
        .Add(Attempt1)
        .Add(Attempt2)
        .Add(Attempt3)
        .Add(Attempt4)
        .Add(Attempt5)
        .Add(Attempt6)
        .Add(Attempt7)
        .Add(Attempt8)
        .Add(Attempt9)
        .Add(Attempt10Part1)
        .Add(Attempt10Part2)
    End With
    With NewControls
        .Add(LetterA)
        .Add(LetterB)
        .Add(LetterC)
        .Add(LetterD)
        .Add(LetterE)
        .Add(LetterF)
        .Add(LetterG)
        .Add(LetterH)
        .Add(LetterI)
        .Add(LetterJ)
        .Add(LetterK)
        .Add(LetterL)
        .Add(LetterM)
        .Add(LetterN)
        .Add(LetterO)
        .Add(LetterP)
        .Add(LetterQ)
        .Add(LetterR)
        .Add(LetterS)
        .Add(LetterT)
        .Add(LetterU)
        .Add(LetterV)
        .Add(LetterW)
        .Add(LetterX)
        .Add(LetterY)
        .Add(LetterZ)
    End With
    With GameWord
        .Add(Me.Letter1)
        .Add(Me.Letter2)
        .Add(Me.Letter3)
        .Add(Me.Letter4)
        .Add(Me.Letter5)
        .Add(Me.Letter6)
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub AllBtnClicks(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles LetterA.Click, LetterB.Click, LetterC.Click, LetterD.Click, LetterE.Click, LetterF.Click, LetterG.Click, LetterH.Click, LetterI.Click, LetterJ.Click, LetterK.Click, LetterL.Click, LetterM.Click, LetterN.Click, LetterO.Click, LetterP.Click, LetterQ.Click, LetterR.Click, LetterS.Click, LetterT.Click, LetterU.Click, LetterV.Click, LetterW.Click, LetterX.Click, LetterY.Click, LetterZ.Click
    'Declartions
    Dim LetterGuess As Button = sender
    LetterGuess.Enabled = False

    Dim LetterCorrect As Boolean = False
    'Loop
    For Each Letter In EndWord
        If GetChar(LetterGuess.Name, 7) = Letter Then
            Select Case Array.IndexOf(EndWord, Letter)
                Case Is = 0
                    Letter1.Visible = True
                Case Is = 1
                    Letter2.Visible = True
                Case Is = 2
                    Letter3.Visible = True
                Case Is = 3
                    Letter4.Visible = True
                Case Is = 4
                    Letter5.Visible = True
                Case Is = 5
                    Letter6.Visible = True
            End Select
            LetterCorrect = True
        End If
    Next
    'Lives left code
    If LetterCorrect = False Then
        AttemptsLeft += 1

        Select Case AttemptsLeft
            Case 1
                Attempt1.Visible = True
                Attempts.Text = 1
            Case 2
                Attempt2.Visible = True
                Attempts.Text = 2
            Case 3
                Attempt3.Visible = True
                Attempts.Text = 3
            Case 4
                Attempt4.Visible = True
                Attempts.Text = 4
            Case 5
                Attempt5.Visible = True
                Attempts.Text = 5
            Case 6
                Attempt6.Visible = True
                Attempts.Text = 6
            Case 7
                Attempt7.Visible = True
                Attempts.Text = 7
            Case 8
                Attempt8.Visible = True
                Attempts.Text = 8
            Case 9
                Attempt9.Visible = True
                Attempts.Text = 9
            Case 10
                Attempt10Part1.Visible = True
                Attempt10Part2.Visible = True
                Attempts.Text = 10
                LetterA.Enabled = False
                LetterB.Enabled = False
                LetterC.Enabled = False
                LetterD.Enabled = False
                LetterE.Enabled = False
                LetterF.Enabled = False
                LetterG.Enabled = False
                LetterH.Enabled = False
                LetterI.Enabled = False
                LetterJ.Enabled = False
                LetterK.Enabled = False
                LetterL.Enabled = False
                LetterM.Enabled = False
                LetterN.Enabled = False
                LetterO.Enabled = False
                LetterP.Enabled = False
                LetterQ.Enabled = False
                LetterR.Enabled = False
                LetterS.Enabled = False
                LetterT.Enabled = False
                LetterU.Enabled = False
                LetterV.Enabled = False
                LetterW.Enabled = False
                LetterX.Enabled = False
                LetterY.Enabled = False
                LetterZ.Enabled = False
                MsgBox("You have lost the round!")
                ResetForm(0)
        End Select


        'Winning a round code
    Else : Dim GameWinner As Boolean = True
        Dim WordCheck As Label
        For Each WordCheck In GameWord
            If Not WordCheck.Visible Then
                GameWinner = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If GameWinner Then
            MsgBox("You have won the round!")
            ResetForm(10)

            'Losing a round code

        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub ResetForm(ScoreForRound As Integer)
    UScore += ScoreForRound
    If Rounds = 3 Then
        Me.Close()
        HighScore.Show()
    Else
        Score.Text = +10
        AttemptsLeft = 0
        Attempts.Text = 0
        Rounds += 1
        Hangman_Load(Nothing, Nothing)
        Dim HangmanReset As PowerPacks.Shape
        For Each HangmanReset In HangmanShapes
            HangmanReset.Visible = False
        Next
        Dim ControlReset As Control
        For Each ControlReset In NewControls
            ControlReset.Enabled = True
        Next
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

**High score form (This is where the user saves their points and also be able to view their high scores afterwards)**

```
   Imports System.IO
   Public Class HighScore
Dim AppPath As String = Application.StartupPath()
Public Username As String
Private Sub HighScore_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim FileData() As String
    Dim SizeArray As Integer
    Try
        FileData = File.ReadAllLines(AppPath & "/highscore.txt")
        SizeArray = FileData.Length
    Catch Break As Exception
        MsgBox("The file is missing!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    For begin = 0 To SizeArray - 1 Step 1
        Me.UserNameLabel.Text = UserNameLabel.Text & FileData(begin) & vbNewLine
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Backtomainmenu_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Backtomainmenu.Click
    MainMenu.Visible = True
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub HelpButtonHighScore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HelpButtonHighScore.Click
    MsgBox("This is the high score, this shows the top 10 players who achieved well in this game, this is ranked by the amount of points score. If you want to have your name in this high score, play the game well in order to achieve this.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
End Sub
'This is where the user saves their high scores
Private Sub SaveName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveName.Click
    Username = NameInput.Text
    Try
        File.WriteAllText(AppPath & "/highscore.txt", Username & " " & UScore)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("The file is missing!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    UScore = vbNull
    If NameInput.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter a name please")
    Else
        File.WriteAllText(AppPath & "/highscore.txt", Username & " " & UScore)
        Me.Close()
        MainMenu.Show()
    End If
End Sub
       End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

> the user is required have at least one character inside the text box

Your code is currently saving to the file **before** any validation occurs:

```
Username = NameInput.Text
Try
    File.WriteAllText(AppPath & "/highscore.txt", Username & " " & UScore)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("The file is missing!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End Try
UScore = vbNull
```

**After** that block of code (which has already written to the file), then you're attempting to validate:

```
If NameInput.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Enter a name please")
Else
    File.WriteAllText(AppPath & "/highscore.txt", Username & " " & UScore)
    Me.Close()
    MainMenu.Show()
End If
```

Consolidate the code, and only write to the file if your validation is successful:

```
Private Sub SaveName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveName.Click
    Username = NameInput.Text.Trim
    If Username = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter a name please!")
    Else
        Try
            File.WriteAllText(AppPath & "/highscore.txt", Username & " " & UScore)
            UScore = vbNull
            Me.Close()
            MainMenu.Show()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error Saving High Score File!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try        
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With `UScore = vbNull`, you might be resetting the score even if `NameInput.Text = ""`.

So, instead of

```
Try
    File.WriteAllText(AppPath & "/highscore.txt", Username & " " & UScore)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("The file is missing!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End Try
UScore = vbNull
If NameInput.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Enter a name please")
Else
    File.WriteAllText(AppPath & "/highscore.txt", Username & " " & UScore)
    Me.Close()
    MainMenu.Show()
End If
```

Put `UScore = vbNull` inside the If statement so

```
Try
    File.WriteAllText(AppPath & "/highscore.txt", Username & " " & UScore)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("The file is missing!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End Try
If NameInput.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Enter a name please")
Else
    File.WriteAllText(AppPath & "/highscore.txt", Username & " " & UScore)
    Me.Close()
    MainMenu.Show()
    UScore = vbNull 'Put it here instead
End If
```